# Excel to Word (Text won't Justify) VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, text-alignment

So to summarize things, I am creating a word document and pasting an excel table into the Word document. The only problem I'm facing now is that the texts in the Word document is aligned left but I want it Justified. However, no matter what I do I can't seem to get it to justify unless I manually do it on Word.

Please find below my code less all the non-relevant stuff. I'm a VBA noob so how I've been doing it is just copy pasting and trying to adapt it to what I need. So far everything works except the justifying part.

```
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If obj Is Nothing Then
    Set obj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
obj.Visible = True

Set objDoc = obj.Documents.Add
a = Sheets("Print").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Print").Range("A1:F" & a).Copy
objDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, True
objDoc.Activate
objDoc.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
Application.CutCopyMode = False
 On Error GoTo 0

With objDoc.Tables(1)
    .PreferredWidth = 505
End With

With objDoc.PageSetup
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.71)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.71)
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.71)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.71)
End With

With objDoc
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpace1pt5
    'set paragraph spacing after to 0
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 10
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
 End With

Sheets("DCN Inputs").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to justify the content in the table, or something else?

Comment: Likely unrelated: You have an `On Error Goto 0`. That means "stop on all errors", and since that's the default setting, that line is unneeded - *unless* you have a `On Error Resume Next` earlier in your code, and if you do - get rid of it during troubleshooting!   Oh and, Welcome by the way! :-)  (Also, see the [tour]!)

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams yes I want to justify the content in table :) I've tried the alignment code on the objDoc.Tables(1) but it didn't work too :(

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks for the warm welcome! Will amend the error thing :)

Comment: @CindyMeister Yes I've tried that already, the table doesn't justify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use the Word enumeration value `wdAlignParagraphJustify` but you don't have a reference to the Word object library. Excel VBA doesn't recognize this member of the Word object model without a specific reference (Tools/References).

If you want to use late-binding, as you have otherwise throughout your code, then you need to substitute the numerical value of the enumeration, which in this case is `3`. For example:

```
objDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, True
objDoc.Activate 
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
With objTable
    .AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
    .PreferredWidth = 505
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 3 'wdAlignParagraphJustify
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Thank you kind Goddess of VBA, it works T.T! I do have one more question, with the current code, the font colour doesn't follow when I paste to word, is it possible to change that ? Or I just need the first cell of the table to be coloured.

Comment: ...and downvote any you consider wrong or "junk". Marking the answer and voting help others recognize what "works".